How can I detect a missing file and not throw an error
I mentioned the xml file path in the xsl, but I want to delete that xml file in the folder for now and I always want to keep in the xsl. But when I'm removing it showing the warning.
<xsl:apply-templates mode="replaceVariables"
            select="document('../Folder_1/Test.xml')">
</xsl:apply-templates>

I deleted the Test.xml from the Folder_1. When I'm running I'm getting the below error
Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7
Severity: warning
Description: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/Work/Folder_1/Test.xml: C:/Work/Folder_1/Test.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
Start location: 674:48
Length: 1

Even though the xml file delete in the corresponding mentioned folder it shouldn't show error while converting.

You stated "you deleted the file" and expect the code to read it?  Some details seem to be missing from your question as the error seems to be what is expected.  Perhaps you mean to ask "How can I detect a missing file and not throw an error?"  or some such?

In XSLT 2.0 and later there is the XPath 2.0 and later function doc-available e.g. doc-available('../Folder_1/Test.xml') so you can use an xsl:if check around your xsl:apply-templates or you might even be able to use the check in a predicate of the select expression.
